# ffmpeg, stretch audio to x seconds

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I am trying to make an audio file be exactly x second.

So far i tried using the `atempo` filter by doing the following calculation

`Audio length / desired length = atempo.`

But this is not accurate, and I am having to tweak the tempo manually to get it to an exact fit.

Are there any other solutions to get this work ? Or am I doing this incorrectly?

My original file is a wav file, and my output in an mp3

Here is a sample command

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -codec:a libmp3lame -filter:a "atempo=0.9992323" -b:a 320K output.mp3
```

**UPDATE**:

I was able to correctly calculate the tempo by changing the way I am receiving the audio length.

I am now calculating the current audio length using the actual file size and the sample rate.

```
Audio Length = file size / (sample rate * 2)
```

Sample rate is something like 16000 Hz. You can get that by using ffprob or ffmpeg.

Comment: How much difference are you getting between desired and obtained duration?

Comment: For a 7 minute audio, the difference is a good 3 to 5 seconds.

Comment: Your originial formula seems right to me.

atempo < 1 makes the audio longer,

atempo > 1 makes it shorter.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atempo

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the tempo incorrectly.

```
Audio length / desired length = atempo
```

should be:

```
desired length / Audio length = atempo
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35515678/3) to the question [ffmpeg, stretch audio to x seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35515678/ffmpeg-stretch-audio-to-x-seconds) by the OP [Max Doumit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1708052/max-doumit) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>