# Stretch Subtitles Timing by Factor

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm muxing an `mkv` video, but the Subtitle `.ssa` file is out of sync by around 1 second by the end of the video.

Delaying the subtitles by 1 second in the beginning is not enough, the timing needs to be stretched to fix an exponentially growing delay. Sync starts out fine in the beginning, but a few milliseconds delay multiplies for each minute that passes.

I fixed them using [MKVToolNix](https://www.fosshub.com/MKVToolNix.html) with **Stretch** `0.999`.

---

**How can I stretch Subtitles using [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org)?**

I saw here how to stretch audio by a factor the same way. [ffmpeg, stretch audio to x seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35515678/6806643)

I'm using something like this:

```
ffmpeg -y 

-fflags +genpts 

-i "video.m4v"  
-i "audio.ac3" 
-i "subs.ssa" 

-c:v copy 
-c:a copy 
-c:s copy 

-map 0:v? 
-map 1:a? 
-map 2:s?

"video.mkv"
```

I used `-itsoffset -00:00:01.000` to remove a gap in the beginning, but it does not stretch.

Comment: Not implemented. Open a ticket at trac.ffmpeg.org of type 'wish'. I'll look into this.

Comment: @Gyan I have opened a ticket https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7292#ticket

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `-itsscale`:

`ffmpeg -itsscale <factor> -i input.srt output.srt`

I don’t know when it was introduced but it sits just below `-itsoffset` in the man page.